# How to build React checkbox tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to work with a checkbox tree component like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-checkbox-tree, except I'm storing the items that I have selected in Redux.  Moreover, the only items that I'm actually storing are the leaf nodes in the tree.  So for example, I'd have the full options data which would be used to render the tree:

```
const fam = {
  cuz2: {
    name: 'cuz2',
    children: {
      cuzKid2: {
        name: 'cuzKid2',
        children: {
        }
      }
    }
  },
  grandpa: {
    name: 'grandpa',
    children: {
      dad: {
        name: 'dad',
        children: {
          me: {
           name: 'me',
           children: {}
          },
          sis: {
           name: 'sis',
           children: {}
          }
        }
      },
      aunt: {
        name: 'aunt',
        children: {
          cuz: {
            name: 'cuz',
            children: {
              name: 'cuzkid',
              children: {}
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and a separate object that stores the items selected.  The following would be the only items that would appear if every checkbox was checked:

```
const selected = {
 cuz2: true,
 me: true,
 sis: true,
 cuz: true
}
```

I seem to be struggling with this method for having the UI determine which boxes to have fully, partially, or un-checked based on the `selected` object.  I was wondering if anyone can recommend another strategy of accomplishing this.

Comment: Try using react-checkbox-tree https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-checkbox-tree

Comment: do anyone have similar solution for react native?

Answer (score 3):

So I have used [react-checkbox-tree](https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-checkbox-tree) but I have customised a bit the icons in order to use another icons library.

[Check my example on sandbox:](https://codesandbox.io/embed/silly-browser-81ff9)

Answer (score 1):

The library provides a [basic example of how to render a tree with selected and/or expanded nodes](https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-checkbox-tree/blob/master/examples/src/js/BasicExample.js).

All you need to do is:

1. [set up the nodes with a unique 'value'](https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-checkbox-tree/blob/master/examples/src/js/BasicExample.js#L6)
2. [Choose which items should be selected (it may comes from Redux)](https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-checkbox-tree/blob/master/examples/src/js/BasicExample.js#L86)
3. pass [nodes & checked list to the CheckBox constructor](https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-checkbox-tree/blob/master/examples/src/js/BasicExample.js#L117)
4. also be sure that when user select/unselect, you update the [UI properly using the state](https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-checkbox-tree/blob/master/examples/src/js/BasicExample.js#L120)

Your code should look similar to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import CheckboxTree from 'react-checkbox-tree';

const nodes = [{
  value: '/cuz2',
  label: 'cuz2',
  children: [],
},
  // other nodes
];

class BasicExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checked: [
      '/cuz2'
    ],
    expanded: [
      '/cuz2',
    ],
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this);
    this.onExpand = this.onExpand.bind(this);
  }

  onCheck(checked) {
    this.setState({
      checked
    });
  }

  onExpand(expanded) {
    this.setState({
      expanded
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      checked,
      expanded
    } = this.state;

    return (<
      CheckboxTree checked={
        checked
      }
      expanded={
        expanded
      }
      nodes={
        nodes
      }
      onCheck={
        this.onCheck
      }
      onExpand={
        this.onExpand
      }
    />
    );
  }
}

export default BasicExample;
```